# Remove custom stopwords in dataframe column in R

Tags: r

I have a custom stopword CSV file and I need to remove those words of a column from a dataframe with texts.

My stoplist is in this file and contains words like these: "em", "de", "o", "para" etc

```
library(tidytext)
stopwords = read.csv2("stopwordPT.csv")
names(stopwords) = "word"
```

my dataframe (tesesResumoUnique) contains data like this image:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufNV0.png

**Text example:**
"Em nosso trabalho estudamos a possibilidade de verificar se, pelas medidas de alguns ossos da mao e carpo, preconizadas por eklof & ringertz, seria possivel de se estabelecer quais as mais confiaveis para se determinar dimorfismo sexual em uma amostra leucoderma da cidade de mogi das cruzes - sp. O total da amostragem constou de 152 individuos, sendo 64 do sexo masculino e 88 do sexo feminino. Quando se aplicou o teste de confiabilidade da amostra pode-se entao constatar que existe possibilidade real de se determinar dimorfismo sexual pelos referenciais de eklof & ringertz, dentro da faixa etaria de 6 a 10 anos que foi objetivo desta pesquisa"

The dataframe has a column called "word" just like the stoplist

```
tesesResumoUnique <- tesesResumoUnique %>% 
  anti_join(stopwords, by = c("word" = "word"))
```

The words are not being deleted from the column. How can I do this ?

Comment: what is your expected outcome? The sentences without the stopwords or the text completely tokenized, but without the stopwords? What you are trying to do now is having a join on the words, but tesesResumoUnique has sentences and the stopwords are single words. That is never going to work.

Answer (score 0):

First, I use both tidyverse and tidytext packages

```
library(tidyverse)
# install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)
```

Second, I create a data.frame with your text

```
df_or <-
  tibble(
    text = "Em nosso trabalho estudamos a possibilidade de verificar se,
    pelas medidas de alguns ossos da mao e carpo, preconizadas por eklof & ringertz, 
    seria possivel de se estabelecer quais as mais confiaveis para se determinar dimorfismo 
    sexual em uma amostra leucoderma da cidade de mogi das cruzes - sp. O total da amostragem
    constou de 152 individuos, sendo 64 do sexo masculino e 88 do sexo feminino.
    Quando se aplicou o teste de confiabilidade da amostra pode-se entao constatar que 
    existe possibilidade real de se determinar dimorfismo sexual pelos referenciais de
    eklof & ringertz, dentro da faixa etaria de 6 a 10 anos que foi objetivo desta pesquisa"
  )
```

But there is problem, the data.frame has only 1 column and 1 row. So, I use the function ***unnest_tokens*** to make that each row be one word of the original text.

```
df <-
  df_or %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = "word",input = "text")
```

Third, I create a data.frame with some stopwords.

```
df_stopwords <-
  tibble(
    word = c("em", "de", "o", "para")
  )
```

Last, I use ***anti_join*** to remove the stopwords

```
df %>% 
  anti_join(df_stopwords)
```